# How to convert q.Now() results to String in fauna

Tags: faunadb

I have createdAt key that I get from

```
Create(Collection("clients"), {
  data: {
    createdAt: Now()
  }
}
```

But the JSON returns

```
"createdAt": {
    "@ts": "2020-11-02T10:09:55.316781Z"
  },
```

How to returns only

```
"createdAt": "2020-11-02T10:09:55.316781Z"
```

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't know why, but after I tried many scenarios, turns out you can get the value with `createdAt.value`

UPDATE: you can convert to string with `ToString()` method before uploading to fauna. e.g. `ToString(Now())`

it'll return `2020-11-02T13:18:23.383908Z`

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

you can use also the **ToString()** method in Fauna:

```
Let(
  {
    date:ToString(Now())
  },
  Create(Collection("clients"),{data:{createdAt:Var('date')}})
)
```

Luigi

Answer (score 0):

I don't have enough reputation to add a comment to [rony's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64643739/6432741), but wanted to mention the Fauna JS Driver documentation at https://fauna.github.io/faunadb-js/module-values-FaunaTime.html does describe the `.value` property of the JS Driver's Fauna Time type:

> If a Date, this is converted to a string.

Here's some sample code I used to convert from a Fauna collection to JSON I can return via API:

```
const post = await this.client.query(
    q.Get(q.Ref(q.Collection('Posts'), id))
);
const dto = {
    id: post.ref.id,
    text: post.data.text,
    title: post.data.title,
    published_at: post.data.publishedAt.value,
};
```

which ends up returning some JSON that looks like this:

```
{
  "id":"293872818653757960",
  "text":"sample text",
  "title":"sample title",
  "published_at":"2021-03-23T16:43:29.309721Z"
}
```